# can i run rshiny application from .net project

Tags: c#, r, shiny

I created an R application with shiny and I have to run it from my project which is in c# to return r results . I  created a view to display results from R but I don't Khnow how to do this . When I googled I found that it is possible to do this with RDCOM but all codes show the connection from a consol and not a view . I used this references:

```
using STATCONNECTORCLNTLib;
using StatConnectorCommonLib;
using STATCONNECTORSRVLib;
```

Then i have to estabilish the connection with rshiny application that I created (server file and ui file).

Comment: I need help !! Any one to answer :(